# I can submit data but won't go to new page -or- go to new page and data doesn't get saved in Django

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

So the title kind of says it all. I have a form based on a model. The goal is to have the specific data entered, user presses submit, data gets saved to a Postgresql DB, user sees complete.html. However this is not the case. I can either get the data to save without changing pages, or the page will change but the data will not submit. I have put details on the specifics of I tried below.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index-page'),
    path('feedback/', views.feedback_view, name = 'feedback'),
    path('complete/', views.complete, name = 'complete')
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class feedback(models.Model):
    RECENT_GROUND = [
        ('PVT','Private'),
        ('INS','Instrument'),
        ('COM','Commercial'),
        ('MEL','Multi-Engine'),
    ]

    RATING = [
        (1,'Poor'),
        (2,'Below Average'),
        (3,'Average'),
        (4,'Above Average'),
        (5,'Excellent'),
    ]
    id_field = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, serialize = True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    spid = models.CharField(primary_key = False, max_length=5, verbose_name = 'Enter the students FSA ID number:')
    recent_ground = models.CharField(max_length = 3, choices = RECENT_GROUND, verbose_name = 'Most recently completed ground school:')
    question1 = models.IntegerField(choices = RATING, verbose_name = 'This is question 1')
    question2 = models.IntegerField(choices = RATING, verbose_name = 'This is question 2')
    question3 = models.IntegerField(choices = RATING, verbose_name = 'This is question 3')
    question4 = models.IntegerField(choices = RATING, verbose_name = 'This is question 4')
    question5 = models.IntegerField(choices = RATING, verbose_name = 'This is question 5')
    question6 = models.IntegerField(choices = RATING, verbose_name = 'This is question 6')
    question7 = models.IntegerField(choices = RATING, verbose_name = 'This is question 7')
    comments = models.TextField(max_length = 500, verbose_name = 'Please leave any additional comments below. If you do not wish to leave comments, type "none".')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
#imports forms class from django
from django import forms
#imports the feedback class from ipfeedbackdb/models.py
from ipfeedbackdb.models import feedback

class feedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = feedback
        fields = "__all__"
        exclude = ['recID','added']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import feedbackForm as feedform

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index/index.html', {'title':' Home'})

# def feedback(request):
#   return render(request, 'index/feedback.html', {'title':' Collection'})

def feedback_view(request):
    context = {}

    form = feedform(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "index/feedback.html", context)

def complete(request):
    return render(request, 'index/complete.html', {'title':' Submitted'})
```

base.html (removed most of the styling to reduce length)

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'index/override.css' %}">


    {% if title %}
      <title>Feedback{{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
      <title>Feedback Site</title>
    {% endif %}
    
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.history.forward();
  function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</script>

  </head>
  <body onload="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
    <div class = 'jumbotron jumbotron-fluid'>
      <div class = 'container'>
        <h2 class = 'display-4' style = 'color:#fff;margin-left: -100px'>FSA</h2>
        <p class = 'lead' style = 'color:#fff;;margin-left: -97px'>Feedback</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock content %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'index/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
      <h2>Index Page</h2>
      <p>This is some more added text.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href = "{% url 'feedback' %}" class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Next -> </a>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

feedback.html (action = "" saves data without changing pages or clearing form, action ="/feedback/" will save but not clear the form or go to another page. action = "/complete/" took me to complete.html but it did not submit the data to the database.)

```
{% extends 'index/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        <h2>Feedback Form Page</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
        <form action = "" method = "post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form| crispy }}
            <input type="submit" name="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

complete.html

```
{% extends 'index/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Your feedback has been submitted. Thank you!</h2>

    <div>
      <a href = "{% url 'index-page' %}" class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Return to start </a>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your feedback view, once forms is valid it doesn't go to *complete*.

```
def feedback_view(request):
    context = {}

    form = feedform(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return render(request, "index/complete.html", context)
    else:  
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, "index/feedback.html", context)
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you!!!! It all works like it supposed to!!!

Answer (score 0):

use button tag!

replace:

```
<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

with:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit">
```

change your view like below

views.py:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def feedback_view(request):
    context = {}

    form = feedform(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('app_name:url_name') # change to where you want to redirect after a successful from submition
            messages.success(request, "Form submitted successfully")
        else:
            messages.warning(request, form.errors)

    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "index/feedback.html", context)
```